# How are the answers with equal up-votes arranged on a page in SO?

Tags: support, answers, answer-order

There should be some ordering. And I just checked, it is not according to the time the answer was given.

What is the ordering?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Answers with the same vote total are put in random order unless there are more than 30 answers, in which case the order is net votes then oldest to newest.

See [How to give some boost to some really good answers that arrive late?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6662/how-to-give-some-boost-to-some-really-good-answers-that-arrive-late/17606#17606):

> We now sort answers of the same score,
>   randomly, per this suggestion.

in response to the [Fastest Gun in the West](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem) "problem" (I say that because I don't think it's a problem at all.

The change caused a problem with questions that had more than one page of answers. See [Random sort order results in answers being “lost” as the user changes to a different page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18931/random-sort-order-results-in-answers-being-lost-as-the-user-changes-to-a-differ/18937#18937):

> When there are more than (pagination
>   limit) answers, the randomization
>   sub-order is removed.

This has been one of SO's more [controversial changes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17624/what-has-happened-to-the-sorting-of-answers-on-stack-overflow) and (imho) not a positive one.

Answer (score 0):

The ordering of answers with the same score is [random](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6662/how-to-give-some-boost-to-some-really-good-answers-that-arrive-late/17606#17606) when ordering by votes:

> We now sort answers of the same score, randomly, per this suggestion.

Comment: okay, excellent!