# Permalink to answer not working (possibly because the answer is not on the first page)

Tags: bug, status-completed, answers, hyperlinks, permalink

This URL (obtained by right-clicking "link" below the answer and selecting "copy link location"):

[Designing function f(f(n)) == -n](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/731832/interview-question-ffn-n/849062#849062)

leads to a blank page.
I assume it is designed to go to whatever page the answer is on, but this is not working.

A workaround is to copy the URL from the page number link:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/731832?tab=votes&page=3#849062

But that relies on the answer staying on the same page, and in CW questions it often does not (except with `?tab-oldest`, but that's probably not the default for many users.)

If this is by design, is there a reliable way to get a permalink to an answer that remains valid if the answer gets pushed down to a different page?

Comment: Works for me ;)

Comment: @ChrisF, If last tab you clicked (oldest/newest/votes) puts that answer on page 1 then it will work.  Try clicking "votes" then try to follow the link again.

Comment: Ah - my default view is newest first. In that case I withdraw my comment.

Comment: i see the issue you're talking about.  by the fact that there's no other obvious permalink offered in the UI, i have to assume this is a valid bug.

Comment: Permalinks for answers on the first page are broken too, and get one one page too far. In fact: this happens for *any* last answer on any page, when sorted on oldest. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38103/pagination-might-cause-permalinks-to-open-the-wrong-page-when-sorted-by-oldest, which I guess is a duplicate (assuming the *blank* page only shows if there's no answers yet on the one-page-too-far page?)

Comment: I don't know if that is the same issue, but I'm pretty sure that a URL that is meant to be a permalink should not be affected by the cookies of whoever happens to follow it.

Comment: @Arjan I think this is more closely related to http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18815/force-permalinked-answers-to-first-page-and-top-of-answer-pile-regardless-of-sort (even though it's tagged "feature-request' not "bug")

Comment: The link works for me.  It takes me to the answer, which is on page three of the answers when sorted by votes.  [Edit]: Oops, now I see a problem.  This link to the last answer (when sorted by votes) doesn't work for me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/731832/interview-question-ffn-n/1149129#1149129  It just takes me to the question.

Comment: Throw some ideas on this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18815/force-permalinked-answers

Comment: I added a screen capture at http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38103/pagination-might-cause-permalinks-to-open-the-wrong-page-when-sorted-by-oldest -- which I guess is what you saw too? That's NOT a blank page then?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has been fixed - it was totally my bad (all the way back from October 2008).

Part of the paging code was using the wrong answers collection; it was **incorrectly using all answers, instead of filtering out deleted answers**.  This behavior would only appear on or near the page boundaries of questions with deleted answers - the more deleted answers, the wider range the bug could appear.

Thanks for finding and researching this! However, I'll not be able to eat today as punishment for introducing a bug ;-)

Comment: This will be pushed to all tiers tonight.

Comment: Look like this issue - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18815/force-permalinked-answers - might be fixed too.

Comment: I don't know whether to down-vote for making the mistake, or up-vote for finally fixing it.

Answer (score 0):

The permalinks implicitly require that you have not changed the default sort order from Votes.

This is [status-bydesign] at the moment.

edit: assuming you have the default votes sort order, my *guess* is that this is sometimes affected by deleted posts; do you guys have the 10k rep to see the deleted posts in these questions?

Comment: I clicked on the "comments" link on one of the OSS ads today and was directed to the wrong page of answers. Why might that happen? (And yes, I have the default sort order.)

Comment: How long is this 'moment' going to last?

Comment: I *was* sorting by votes, as stated in the question.  Unfortunately you can't see the problem with the answer I linked anymore as it has been upvoted from -1 to 0.

Comment: @Jeff, Possibly.  My rep is 5K, but mmeyers has 23K.

Comment: @Jeff, how about rendering the question page(s) to figure out where the linked question should be?  If someone has clicked the link you're going to have to render it anyway.  Would it be a disaster if you occasionally rendered the wrong page first and had to discard the result?

Comment: @perpetual mmeyers does *not* have 10k rep on meta, which is what he was referring to.