# Don't use random as secondary sorting for multi page questions

Tags: bug, status-completed, sorting

When looking at **deleted** questions with many answers, and answers with the same score span page breaks, which ends up on which page changes all the time. And that's very annoying. Don't do that.

[Jeff claims that it's already disabled for multi page questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/18938/152255), but that's clearly not true, so I'll tag this as bug, instead of feature request.

For example, refresh the following link a few times: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2349378/new-programming-jargon-you-coined?page=8&tab=votes#tab-top (SO 10k only)

Comment: Ah, if 10k only, then it's probably related to deleted answers, [which was fixed earlier too](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38103/pagination-might-cause-permalinks-to-open-the-wrong-page-no-matter-what-sorting/38800#38800), but might be back?

Comment: No idea if it's specific to deleted answers, it's just that most of those many-answer questions are deleted. I observed this several times, and I think some were not deleted at the time.

Comment: Not being 10k (hence not being able to see deleted *answers* in non-closed questions either), I cannot reproduce this. Like [for page 5 of this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1995113/strangest-language-feature?page=5&tab=votes#tab-top) that has 320 answers. (You can search for questions with many answers [by using `answers:300`](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=answers%3A300).)

Comment: OK, can't reproduce it with that question either. It's also not related to historical locking, since http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8472/practical-non-image-based-captcha-approaches?page=2&tab=votes#tab-top doesn't exhibit the issue. So you're probably right that it's specific to deleted questions/answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was fixed last week and I forgot to inform you about it.