# "Unbiased" tab layout

Tags: feature-request, voting, design

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Real random ordering of answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49348/real-random-ordering-of-answers)

As we all know, there are "active", "oldest", "votes" tabs for answers at stackexchange. 
I suggest to add a tab the could be for example called "unbiased". In this view, the answers are sorted randomly and all votes, comments and acceptance check are hidden. But the viewer still can vote for himself (probably a single check at the area where all scores are placed).

The objective behind this is because our actions are always biased, either by something we see first (or not seeing something at all if it's last) or by seeing how others react on the subject. This view would probably allow judging independently.

Comment: On a personal note I use "oldest" as I think there *should* be a bias toward older answers.

Comment: @Mr. Wizard not a perfect duplicate though, as the OP here requests not showing votes and comments as well

Comment: @Pekka okay, I agree.

Comment: I guess this is kind of helpful for applying random votes (and I do mean random) but this seems pretty useless for those hoping to see the most relevant answer in any sense of the word (earliest best answer, most up to date answer, most agreed on as correct...)

Comment: An interesting idea.

Comment: @Jeff it's not a duplicate of that question.

Answer (score 4):

It's an interesting idea, and not expensive to implement, either.

Maybe the tab could be named differently, say `Neutral`.

While we're at it, it *might* be an idea to hide authors' identities, or at least their reputation counts. Although that might be too much.

However, I don't agree that *comments* should be hidden. They can contain valuable information pertinent to the question.

Comment: I seemed liked "Neutral" more than "Unbiased". And forgot about identities, thanks.