# Answers are not sorted properly

Tags: support, answer-order

I don't know if I'm having a slow internet connection but I'm still reporting this. Sometimes the answers to my questions are not sorted properly. Having 3 answers in my questions, when I refresh the page, the order also changes.

Has someone also experienced it? I assume that the 1st answer is the one you marked checked and the rest are ordered by date/time, oldest answer first.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answers are sorted a few ways, it depends which tab you have selected on top of the answers:

- **oldest** - Oldest answer first, etc
- **newest** - Newest answer first, etc
- **votes** - Answers are shorted by votes. If there's only one page of answers then answers are *not* sorted by date/time: the order is then random past the vote sort (intentionally). If there are multiple pages, then [no randomization](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18655/random-sorting-appears-to-screw-with-answer-permalinks/18938#18938) in the vote order is done.

The default sort is votes.
Also, when viewing by votes the accepted is only at the top if the OP didn't accept their *own* answer (usually the case, that's a minority by far).

Comment: know i know that this is not a bug. thanks nick for the clarification. im a new member and im enjoying sharing ideas here in stackoverflow.. thanks :)

Answer (score 6):

This is by design. Answers with an equal number of upvotes will be displayed in random order for fairness.

Comment: ...if sorted on votes, and unless pagination kicks in, in which case posts with the same vote count [are listed by creation date](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18655/random-sorting-appears-to-screw-with-answer-permalinks/18938#18938).