# How are answers with the same vote score sorted?

Tags: discussion, answers, sorting

When a new question is asked how are the answers sorted?  I just answered a question and there were two other answers.  All three answers have 0 votes and no edits.

Immediately after I answered my answer appeared first.  Now the order refreshed,  it appears they are sorted by reputation.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

When sorting by votes (which is the default) and there is just one page of answers, then answers with the same number of votes are shown in random order relative to each other.

If there are multiple pages, then [no randomization is used](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18655/random-sorting-appears-to-screw-with-answer-permalinks/18938#18938).

Comment: Yes, they are ordered randomly, and the order changes all times you watch the question.