# What is the sort order of the answers?

Tags: support, answers, sorting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How are answers sorted?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107096/how-are-answers-sorted)

In a question, I see that each time I refresh the page, the answers were placed in a different order. The question has 3 answers each with zero votes. The users' reputation was something like 6, 1200, and 7300 but these numbers didn't affect the order.

What is the criteria of the sort order of the answers?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming you're viewing the question with the answers sorted by Votes, the accepted answer floats to the top*, followed by the answers in descending order by votes. If the answers are tied, they are sorted randomly.

*If the accepted answer was posted by the OP, it gets sorted regularly and doesn't float to the top.

Comment: They seems to be sorted randonly.

Comment: "The accepted answer floats to the top"! What if the accepted answer is wrong and has a huge difference in votes with the next one. Example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4701532/force-maven-update

Answer (score 20):

The tab at the Answers section will let you know the sort order

[image]

- Active: Sorted with answer with recent activity (edits etc) being on top
- Oldest: Sorted with answer with oldest answer (edits etc) being on top
- Votes: Sorted with answer with most votes (edits etc) being on top

If an answer has been accepted, it'll always be pinned as the first.

If the sort order is votes and the answers have same number of votes, I believe the answers with same votes will be sorted randomly.

Comment: Thanks for helping me figure out the sorting weirdness I was seeing, as I've never _ever_ seen tabs used to change the sort order of a list... they're supposed to show/hide, not sort.