# Sorting order of Answers having same votes

Tags: support, answers, sorting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How are answers sorted?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107096/how-are-answers-sorted)

On default *sort by votes* tab, how are answers with same votes sorted?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Randomly, unless there's…

- … an accepted answer. The accepted answer by someone other than the asker will be at the top.
- … more than one page of answers. In that case, they're sorted by both votes *and* creation date (i.e., older posts will be above newer posts with the same score).

Comment: I thought there was a time component to it?

Comment: @agf I don't think there is, unless there are at least 2 pages of answers. Not sure why this is, but an answer "sliding" between pages randomly probably caused some issues.

Comment: Indeed, [randomization caused issues](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18655/random-sorting-appears-to-screw-with-answer-permalinks/18938#18938) when pagination kicked in.