# What's the "link" under each answer used for?

Tags: support, permalink, hyperlinks

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does the “link” thingy do?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18635/what-does-the-link-thingy-do)

I've noticed a link entitled, "link" under each answer (beside the "flag" link).

When I click on it, nothing happens.

What's the use of the "link" then?

Comment: see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18635/what-does-the-link-thingy-do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gives you the URL of the page with that answers anchor appended to it, so you can email a link directly to the answer you want to share it with... :-)

Comment: thank you, beggs. so the URL was saved in the buffer, what I need is just paste it?
Let me see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18635/what-does-the-link-thingy-do.

Comment: Clicking on `link` does not save it to the buffer... you have to right-click and copy link (or whatever your browser says) or just click and copy the link from the location bar after the page loads.