# How do I link to an Answer, rather than the Question?

Tags: support, answers, hyperlinks, permalink

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I link to a specific answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45597/how-can-i-link-to-a-specific-answer)

I was trying to include in one of my responses a link to a prior SO answer to give the right credit. However I couldn't find any information on how to pick up / create the specific link to the Answer.

It is fairly easy to link to a Question by right clicking its title, but I can't find any place to pick-up the link to a specific answer within the Q&A. I know it can be done as VonC and others have given great references to some of my questions. I'm just not able to pass on the favour.

So, how do I get the link to a specific answer?

Comment: Under every post, whether question or answer, there's a "link" button that you can use.

Comment: Under the tags, there's a 'link' link. You can click that to get the permalink to a question / answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I link to a specific answer?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45597/how-can-i-link-to-a-specific-answer), [What does the “link” thingy do?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18635/what-does-the-link-thingy-do), [What's the “link” under each answer used for?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32390/whats-the-link-under-each-answer-used-for)

Comment: @Cody: Definately sounds like it should be an FAQ then;-). Especially as all the answers have been removed from the main site....

Comment: @Philip: Most people have found this feature to be extremely discoverable. The "link" link is right there next to the "edit" link and the "flag" link, two things that people are already using. And yes, it was migrated away from the main site because discussion *about* Stack Overflow should never happen *on* Stack Overflow. We have a separate site set up for that to keep down the noise, and it's called Meta. That much *is* explained in the FAQ.

Answer (score 4):

Below each answer is a "link" button:

[image: Screenshot of link button]

Press it to get a link to that answer.

Comment: I kept clicking on the "close" link until I realized it was a screenshot.

Answer (score 3):

There's a label called "link" on the answer, which - not surprisingly - links to it.

Comment: Unfortunately it wasn't "obvious", partly because it's gray, partly because its in a group that doesn't feel realted to the action, but, for me, I was expecting there to be an actual link underneath a title, or the score number.

Answer (score 2):

As others have already pointed, there is a link below the answer. Here is a screenshot showing links with respect to both question and answer.

[image: Link]

Comment: I expected [expection from other web pages] the link to be available as part of a 'title', as is present for the title [Question] in the screen shot. E.g. the last link should be avaliable as part of the "6" score, perhaps labelled as "Lance Roberts answer" etc.